# GOJS second diagrams's zoom issue

Tags: diagram, zooming, gojs

I have two GOJS diagrams on a same page. one is primary diagram. It gets data on page load and displays the nodes. and it also has a search to find path between nodes.
Search takes source node and destination node. then on search action, the second diagram only displays the nodes involved in search and their links.

I am using mouse wheel for zoom in and zoom out.

```
mainDiagram.addDiagramListener("InitialLayoutCompleted", function (e) {
    e.diagram.toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior = go.ToolManager.WheelZoom;
});
```

primary diagram has no issue. but the second diagram's zoom does not work. Following is the code for my second diagram.

```
var myPathDiagram = _go(go.Diagram, "policyPathDiv",
        {
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center, 
            layout: _go(go.LayeredDigraphLayout,
                    {direction: 0}),
            autoScale: go.Diagram.UniformToFill,
            maxSelectionCount: 1,
            "undoManager.isEnabled": false,
            hasHorizontalScrollbar: false,
            hasVerticalScrollbar: false,
        });
```

then tools manager setting

```
 myPathDiagram.addDiagramListener("InitialLayoutCompleted", function (e) {
     e.diagram.toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior = go.ToolManager.WheelZoom;
 });
```

Second diagram gets the data on search action with following code.

```
myPathDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodes, links);
```

Everything is right except zoom on second diagram. keyboard shortcut **ctrl +** and **ctrl -** also doesn't work for second diagram.

I tried many things, but so far i am not able to make the zoom work on second diagram. any suggestion please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set **Diagram.autoScale** if you want the user to scale (a.k.a. zoom) the diagram.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. strangely `autoScale: go.Diagram.UniformToFill` in primary diagram is not causing zoom to stop functioning, but in secondary diagram commenting this line solved the issue.